# BeautifulSoup parent tag

Tags: python, html-parsing, beautifulsoup

I have some html that I want to extract text from. Here's an example of the html:

```
<p>TEXT I WANT <i> &#8211; </i></p>
```

Now, there are, obviously, lots of `<p>` tags in this document. So, `find('p')` is not a good way to get at the text I want to extract. However, that `<i>` tag is the only one in the document. So, I thought I could just find the `<i>` and then go to the parent.

I've tried:

```
up = soup.select('p i').parent
```

and

```
up = soup.select('i')
print(up.parent)
```

and I've tried it with `.parents`, I've tried `find_all('i')`, `find('i')`... But I always get:

```
'list' object has no attribute "parent"
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This works:

```
i_tag = soup.find('i')
my_text = str(i_tag.previousSibling).strip()
```

**output:**

```
'TEXT I WANT'
```

As mentioned in other answers, `find_all()` returns a list, whereas `find()` returns the first match or `None`

If you are unsure about the presence of an i tag you could simply use a `try/except` block

Comment: sooo this looks like (for bs4) node.find_parent()

Answer (score 26):

`find_all()` returns a list. `find('i')` returns the *first* matching element, or `None`.

The same applies to `select()` (returns a list) and `select_one()` (first match or `None`).

Thus, use:

```
try:
    up = soup.find('i').parent
except AttributeError:
    # no <i> element
```

Demo:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup('<p>TEXT I WANT <i> &#8211; </i></p>')
>>> soup.find('i').parent
<p>TEXT I WANT <i> – </i></p>
>>> soup.find('i').parent.text
u'TEXT I WANT  \u2013 '
```

Comment: Worth noting is that if you want to use css selectors, you can also do `soup.select('.foo').parent`.

Comment: @fgblomqvist: no, `.select()` returns a list. It'd work with `soup.select_one('.foo').parent`.

Comment: my bad, that's what I meant to write.

Answer (score 6):

`soup.select()` returns a Python List.  So you have 'unlist' the variable
e.g.:

```
>>> [up] = soup.select('i')
>>> print(up.parent)
```

or

```
>>> up = soup.select('i')
>>> print(up[0].parent)
```

Comment: Or, use `select_one()`.

Answer (score 5):

Both `select()` and `find_all()` return you an array of elements. You should do like follow:

```
for el in soup.select('i'):
    print el.parent.text
```

Comment: At first redaction of the question there were nothing about what is really required. I've updated my code sample.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually looking in a group of these kind of tags.The select function actually returns list of mentioned tags so if you are asking for the parent tag,it doesn't know which member of the list do you mean.Try

```
    up = soup.select('p i')[0].parent
    print(up)
```

this will tell that you are actually looking for the parentof first one in the list ('[0]').I don't know this will work just try it out.